# Python script to check which item of list has changed?

Tags: python, list

I have a code where I am comparing the 2 list and then telling the user, index of the item changed and what is changed value. Below is the code

```
default_io = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

while True:
    lst = []
    n = int(input("Enter number of elements : "))
    for i in range(0, n):
        ele = int(input())
        lst.append(ele)  # adding the element

    new_list = list(set(lst).difference(default_io))
    print(new_list)
    if new_list:
        print("io{}".format(lst.index(new_list[0])+1))
    else:
        print("no change")

    default_io = lst
```

Initially I am taking a default_io list which will compare first time with the list which user will enter. During 2nd time, we have to compare the list which user entered 1st time with the list which he will enter now and it will keep on going.

So for first time, I have entered list [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1] and if we compare it with default_io [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], we can see 5th element has changed from 1 to 0. Running the code also shows the same output:

```
Enter number of elements : 6
1
1
1
1
0
1
[0]
io5
```

But during 2nd time, I have entered list [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] which should ideally be compared with the list I entered previously i.e. [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1] and output should be that 5th element has changed from 0 to 1 but the output is :

```
Enter number of elements : 6
1
1
1
1
1
1
[]
no change
```

I am not able to understand why its showing wrong output. I need to compare the list and predict which index element has changed. Please help. Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36285916/is-copy-copy-different-from-assignment-in-python

Comment: @jarmod sorry I am not able to understand.

Answer (score 1):

- Let's start with the basics. Take `setA = {1, 2, 3}` and `setB = {2, 3, 4}` `setA - setB` will return all the values that are in `setA` and not in `setB` in this case it will return `1`, because `1` is present in `setA` and not in `setB`.
- Now let us see what `setB-setA` will return, as you might have guessed, it would return 4, because 4 is present in `setB` and not in `setA`.   **An important point to note here is `setA-setB` != `setB-setA`** .
- Now coming to your program. Initially your list is `default_io = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` and now you add some values to a temp list `lst=[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]`. And according to the logic you implemented  `set(lst).difference(default_io)` will return `0`, because it is present in `lst` and not present in `default_io`.
- In your second iteration your `default_io=[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]` and `lst=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` and `set(lst).difference(default_io)` will give you empty set because `default_io` contains `1`, whereas `set(default_io).difference(lst)` will give you the result you expected.

So an ideal solution could be (which you can obviously improve upon):

```py
new_list = [[x, index] for index, (x, y) in enumerate(itertools.zip_longest(lst, default_io)) if x!=y]
```

which gives you both the correct index and value which was changed.

---

Why I suggest against the use `set` or `set.symmetric_difference` as this [answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67905643/15993687) for your problem.

For example let us take `default_io=[2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1]` and you input `lst=[2, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1]`

now let's use `set.symmetric_difference` as the answer suggested.

```py
set([2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1]).symmetric_difference([2, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1])
```

output:

```
{0}
```

whereas the first difference should have been `2` as `2` changed first.

So why did this happen. Let us examine:

when you passed your list into a set it removes duplicates.

So here `set([2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1])` becomes `{1, 2, 3}` and `set([2, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1])` becomes `{0, 1, 2, 3}`.

As we know set difference returns values that are either in `setA` or `setB` but not in their intersection, so in this case, it returns `0` which is not your expected output.

Another case where it might not work:

```py
set1=[2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1]
set2=[2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1]
# op: set() <-- empty
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy

default_io = numpy.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])

while True:
    lst = []
    n = int(input("Enter number of elements : "))
    for i in range(0, n):
        ele = int(input())
        lst.append(ele)  # adding the element
    lst = numpy.array(lst)
    new_list = default_io - lst

    if list(new_list) == [0,0,0,0,0,0]:
      print("no change")
    else:
      li = []
      for i in new_list:
        if i != 0:
          li.append(list(new_list).index(i))
      print(li)
      print("change")
    default_io = lst
```

Simply said, if you were to subtract 2 sets, the indexes with the value of zero means the same value were at the index of each list. if it has value other than 0, it means a change happened at that index.

Answer (score 0):

Your code, on the 2nd iteration, is essentially calculating:

```
set([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]).difference([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1])
```

which is equivalent to:

```
{1}.difference([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1])
```

The result of this is an empty set:

```
set()
```

Why does it return an empty set? Because the [set.difference(iterable)](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/sets/difference.html) method works as follows:

> Returns a new set with elements in the set that are not in the specified iterables.

Specifically, the set contains the value 1, and only 1, which is indeed in the iterable list so the result is an empty set. The fact that 0 also appears in the iterable is irrelevant to the difference method.

Instead, you should use [symmetric_difference](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/sets/symmetric_difference.html), which:

> Returns a new set with elements in either the set or the specified iterable but not both.

For example:

```
set([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]).symmetric_difference([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1])
# result is {0}
```