# Finding changes made to lists

Tags: python

So I'm trying to find the items that went in and went out of a list before and after it changed

For example, at first my list is:

```
[1, 1, 2, 5, 7, 7]
```

And then a minute later it's:

```
[1, 2, 2, 5, 6, 7, 4]
```

How would I end up with 2 lists that show what items went out and which went in like so,

```
itemsOut = [1,7]
itemsIn = [2, 6, 4]
```

Position and length can change

Comment: Have you searched for "difference between lists"?

Comment: `items_out, items_in = zip(*(p for p in zip(old, new) if p[0] != p[1]))`

Comment: does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67902079/python-script-to-check-which-item-of-list-has-changed) your question?

Comment: @OlvinRoght assumes position matters, right? but q is undefined: does appending to the list count as 'item in'?

Comment: @2e0byo, good questions to wrong person. I gave answer assuming that position matters and list length won't be changed. There's no strict requirements in question body, so..

Comment: @2e0byo Sorry guys it's my first time posting here, position doesn't matter and length can change, edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Counter` from the built-in `collections` module:

```py
>>> list1 = [1, 1, 2, 5, 7, 7]
>>> list2 = [1, 2, 2, 5, 6, 7, 4]

>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counter1 = Counter(list1)
>>> counter2 = Counter(list2)
>>> l_diff = counter1-counter2
>>> r_diff = counter2-counter1
>>> print(list(l_diff))
[1, 7]
>>> print(list(r_diff))
[2, 6, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this, to detect wich items changed.

```
old_arr = [1, 2, 2, 5, 7, 7]
new_arr = [1, 1, 2, 5, 7, 7]
items_out = []
for element in old_arr:
    if new_arr.count(element) > 0:
        new_arr.pop(new_arr.index(element))
    else:
        items_out.append(element)
print("Items out:", items_out)
print("Items in:", new_arr)
```